# A simple try catch doesn't work Powershell

Tags: powershell, try-catch

So i'm doing a robocopy with Powershell. And all i want is to write a logfile. The Robocopy works but the try and catch doesnt work. Here is my Powershell-Code:

```
function Write-Log{[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[ValidateSet("INFO","WARN","ERROR","FATAL","DEBUG")]
[String]
$level = "INFO",

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]
$message ,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]
$logfile
)

$timeStamp = (Get-Date).toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
$line = "$timeStamp $level $message"
if($logfile) {
    Add-Content $logfile -Value $line
} else {
    Write-Output $line
}}


try {C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\robocopy.exe "C:\Users\boriv\Desktop\por" "C:/users/boriv/desktop/1" robocopy *.* /MIR /EFSRAW /DCOPY:DAT /A+:R /A-:AE /IA:ACEHNORST /V /BYTES}

catch { Write-Log -message "Der Kopiervorgang war nicht erfolgreich" -logfile "C:\users\boriv\Desktop\$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).txt" -level ERROR}

Write-Log -message "Der Kopiervorgang war erfolgreich" -logfile "C:\users\boriv\Desktop\$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).txt" -level INFO
```

Comment: ROBOCOPY has a /LOG or /LOG+ option. Can you just use that? I do not understand what you were trying to accomplish with the try catch. If there was no error then nothing would be logged.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman No I can't use the ROBOCOPY LOG option because i want to have every day a new logfile. I can't do that with robocopy. But also when in the try phrase a mistake in is it doesn't go to the catch. It will stop.

Comment: I mean it is an option: robocopy.exe ... /LOG:"C:\users\boriv\Desktop\$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use exception handling for an external process (which is what `robocopy.exe` is).

Instead, you should use `$LASTEXITCODE` to determine the status of the execution. Each individual external command has different exit codes that mean different things (though `0` nearly universally means Success).

[See the very last section here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/) for information on handling external errors.

[A list of robocopy exit codes is available here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2008/06/16/robocopy-exit-codes/) and offers this information:

> ```
> 0 No errors occurred and no files were copied.
> 1 One of more files were copied successfully.
> 2 Extra files or directories were detected.  Examine the log file for more information.
> 4 Mismatched files or directories were detected.  Examine the log file for more information.
> 8 Some files or directories could not be copied and the retry limit was exceeded.
> 16 Robocopy did not copy any files.  Check the command line parameters and verify that Robocopy has enough rights to write to the destination folder.
> ```
>
> I strongly recommend that you use the /LOG parameter with Robocopy in
> order to create a complete log file of the process.  This file is
> invaluable for finding out what went wrong.

Also [RoelVB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3914218/roelvb) added a very useful comment:

> Note that the exit codes are bit wise for robocopy and can be combined. You could for example get exit code 3, which is a combination of 1 and 2

Comment: Note that the exit codes are bit wise for robocopy and can be combined.
You could for example get exit code 3, which is a combination of 1 and 2

Comment: @RoelVB thanks for this comment from a few months ago. I've edited it into the answer.