# Move a List of Folders from csv File without losing the permissions

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting, robocopy

I am trying to move a list of user folders to a new file server so I need to keep the permissions intact. For that I am using robocopy. The problem is, it will only move the files and subfolders inside the source folder but not the source folder itself. this is the script I am using:

```
   function Move-Folders {
   param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [string]$Csv
   )

   $folders = Import-Csv -Path $Csv
   $Target = "\\Server\share\"

   foreach ($folder in $folders) {
       $folderPath = $folder.Path
       Write-Host "moving folder $folderPath"

       try {
           robocopy $folderPath $Target /E /COPYALL /MOVE /NP
       } catch {
           $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
           Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Error Moving folder $folderPath : $errorMessage"
       }
   }
}
```

also it will not display the error message I wrote in the catch, if an Error occurred.
Can someone please help. how do I get the command to move the source folders that is writen in the CSV file
this is my first time using Robocopy so if you guys have any modifications to the command feel free to add it.
The csv Path Column is writen this way \\Server\folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get the directoryname itself with:

```
$dir = $folderPath -replace ".*\\"
```

Then adding the directory Name to the robocopy command:

```
robocopy "$folderPath\" "$Target\$dir" /E /COPYALL /MOVE /NP
```

Complete Script would then look like this:

```
function Move-Folders {
   param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [string]$Csv
   )

   $folders = Import-Csv -Path $Csv
   $Target = "\\Server\share"

   foreach ($folder in $folders) {
       $folderPath = $folder.Path
       Write-Host "moving folder $folderPath"

       $dir = $folderPath -replace ".*\\"

       try {
           robocopy "$folderPath\" "$Target\$dir" /E /COPYALL /MOVE /NP
       } catch {
           $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
           Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Error Moving folder $folderPath : $errorMessage"
       }
   }
}
```

Maybe it would be just better to edit the CSV File with more informations and getting the needed Folders directly from the CSV.

Comment: Thanx for the speedy answer. that did it for the robocopy command. it works. but I still have the Problem with catch if an error occurd, it will only display the output of the robocopy command. do you know how I could change that. or someother way to log only the errors.

Comment: @Hidden_Name , take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637632/a-simple-try-catch-doesnt-work-powershell

You can't use exception handling for an external process (which is what robocopy.exe is).

Comment: Thank you for the help. if I understod the article correctly. External commands will only give a code that will be saved in the $LastExitCode Variable. I will just use the /LOG Parameter in the command I guess. Thank you for the Information. I will mark this as the Answer